# JBoss 5.X Clustered, how to send a Multicast Message?

Tags: session, jboss5.x, cluster-computing, apache2.2

I've 2 instances of JBoss (5.1.0 GA) in a cluster and an Apache 2.2 mod jk to do the balance. They are working fine, the sessions are replicated correctly.

What I'd like to do is: Send a message (could be a multicast message) for all JBoss (nodes) in my cluster, to do a custom operation, for example to reload some objects from database to a memory.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me, how can I do this?

Cheers,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the topic producer & MDBs as topic subscriber on each node...
But It was not workingas the nodes post office was not clustered one.

I change jboss nodes post office to clustered as

```
  <!-- This post office is non clustered. If you want a clustered post office then set to true -->

  <attribute name="Clustered">true</attribute>
```

and now I start getting notification on all nodes, which signals me to update the cache.